# Is there a step-through debugger for Haskell?

Tags: debugging, haskell

Is there a step-through debugger or similar for Haskell?

Comment: I would also suggest just testing each small function in an interpreter when possible.  As Haskell is functional, this is much easier, as each function can stand by itself.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

GHCi has an [included debugger](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.5/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#the-ghci-debugger).

Don Stewart wrote a nice [introductory tutorial](https://donsbot.wordpress.com/2007/11/14/no-more-exceptions-debugging-haskell-code-with-ghci/) some time ago.

There's also [hood](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hood), which lets you observe intermediate structures.

Some older projects, such as hat, seem to have fallen into bitrot/off the internet.

Note – all the above packages are text-based and platform independent.