# How can I print all the steps that this code is going through?

Tags: haskell

I have this code in haskell:

```
getMax :: [Integer] -> Integer
    getMax dlis = foldr (\ next max_so_far ->
                        if (next > max_so_far)
                            then next 
                            else max_so_far)
                        (head dlis) (tail dlis)

list = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I run it in ghci like `getMax list`and returns 5. I sort of understand what is going on, but I would like to make it print every step that it is taking(the numbers being compared). How can I do that ?

Modified program :

```
getMax :: [Integer] -> Integer
    getMax dlis = foldr (\ next max_so_far ->
                        if (traceThis next > traceThat max_so_far)
                            then next
                            else max_so_far)
                        (head dlis) (tail dlis)

    traceThis :: (Show a) => a -> a
    traceThis x = trace ("Comparing: " ++ show x) x

    traceThat :: (Show a) => a -> a
    traceThat x = trace (" with: " ++ show x) x
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a step-through debugger for haskell on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901902/is-there-a-step-through-debugger-for-haskell-on-windows)

Comment: it's probably not exactly what you are looking for but have you tried [`trace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:trace)?

Comment: @Mephy I'll look into that

Comment: @Carsten no, I have not. I'll give it a try

Comment: it's like going back 20yrs but it actually helped me a few times ;)

Comment: @Carsten how do I have to modify it to use trace ?

Comment: for example you could do `(\ next max_so_far -> trace ("called with " ++ show next) $ ...rest of your code)` and you should get traces of each of the steps in a hopefully obvious manner

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you

Comment: your function isn't safe: it crashes on []. you could make it return a Maybe Integer instead.

Comment: @ErikAllik I just want to see how the foldr works in this case, but from the modified program I still don't get something that will tell me 100% how it works . I get for getMax [1,5,6,2,2] :` Comparing: 5 Comparing: 6 Comparing: 2 Comparing: 2 with: 1 with: 2 with: 2 with: 6 `

Comment: The best educational step-by-step evaluator is [lambda bubble pop](http://chrisuehlinger.com/LambdaBubblePop/). Too bad it supports only a limited subset of Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main approaches here:

First, you can use the `trace` function. (You need to import `Debug.Trace` first.) This takes a string to print and a value to return. It only prints the string when (if) the value gets "used" (Haskell is lazy, remember). This can result in stuff being printed in a really weird order sometimes. Obviously, this method requires actually changing your code to sprinkle it with `trace` calls.

Second, you can use the GHCi debugger, as described in [the GHC User Manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html). Personally I've never had that much luck with it, but the option if there if you want to try it. And it doesn't require changing any code.

Sadly, there is no button that just says "print out what you're doing". That would be extremely useful, and is a highly-requested feature, but never seems to get created... :-(

**Edit** I see that you're trying to do something like this:

```
if trace (show x) x > trace (show y) y then ...
```

The trouble is, it is *undefined* which `trace` will get executed first. You probably want to do something more like

```
if trace (show x ++ " > " ++ show y) (x > y) then ...
```

Comment: I tried using trace, but I get `Not in scope: 'trace' `. As for the second I haven't figured out how to use it.

Comment: As I said, *you need to import `Debug.Trace` first*.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Missed that. As for the second solution  how do I set those break points ?

Comment: Near the top of the manual page I linked to, it seems to suggest that `:break` <line number> will do it.

Comment: After modifying the if line to include trace and running the program, I get for `getMax [1,5,6,2,2]` :` Comparing: 5
Comparing: 6
Comparing: 2 
Comparing: 2
 with: 1
 with: 2
 with: 2
 with: 6 ` ...

Comment: @BogdanDaniel Depending on how you modified the `if` line, this is running into the dangers of interleaving side-effects and laziness. You need to make sure the line is printed before the comparison is done. How exactly did you write your modified program?